# What applescript data type would I use for this?

Tags: applescript

I have got this applescript code:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    set test to the bounds of window 1
end tell

display dialog test
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
error "Can’t make {10, 22, 400, 1003} into type string." number -1700
from {10, 22, 400, 1003} to string
```

Which data type would I need to use for this?

BTW, I don't want it to display `10224001003` as it does when you set it to some data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A display dialog statement can only display a string. The window bounds is returned to you as a list of numbers. As such you have to create a string out of that information so you can display it. There's several ways to do that but here's a simple way where we just create a new string and insert the bounds numbers into that string however we want. You can see that I made the new string look like the list of numbers... but it really is a string.

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    set boundsList to the bounds of window 1
end tell

set boundsString to "{" & ((item 1 of boundsList) as text) & ", " & ((item 2 of boundsList) as text) & ", " & ((item 3 of boundsList) as text) & ", " & ((item 4 of boundsList) as text) & "}"
display dialog boundsString
```